# How to create dynamic url and content like wordpress in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create dynamic url and content like wordpress platform but I am doing something wrong. Kindly check my code:

```
<?php

$pages = array("story1", "story2", "story3");

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>This is my page title.</title>
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.xyz1.com/kids-english-<?php 
 echo $pages[1];?>.php"/> 
 <!-- here the url is creating but gives error 404 -->
 </head>

 <body>
  <p>Hello, <?php echo $pages[1];?></p><br>
  <a  href="http://www.xyz1.com/kids-english-<?php echo $pages[1];?>.php"><?php echo $pages[2];?></a>

 <!-- here the second url is creating but gives error 404 -->

 </body>
 </html>
```

Now I want to get the content from database and want to load somefile.php

Here starts my second problem. I create urls by foreach loop but how to load all the content to somefile.php and how will one somefile.php will handle all the different urls and different content created dynamically. I am confused here.

Your suggestions would be welcome.
Thank You.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your PHP `echo` statements are hooked up so the user will correctly be taken to `/kids-english-story2.php`. You actually have to **build** those various independent PHP pages for them to not give you 404s. There's no reference to a loop nor `somefile.php` in your code.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because it's suggesting a package, but you can use something like http://altorouter.com/ if you don't want to go full WP and/or do a lot of coding. NOTE: As of time of posting it's listed as "Build Failing". We use it and it's fine but not sure if something has been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. applications like Wordpress, Shopware and so on are built on a MVC-Design scheme like every other good coded project.

You can go for frameworks like Symfony or build your own routing mechanism.

All in all it's a little bit more tricky as you did mentioned your thoughts.